# Can I use a dictionary in this way

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently revising for my GCSE coursework. The Task I have been asked for is a troubleshooting program, in which the user says their problem; and I evaluate their input and test it for keywords, before pulling up a text file into the code and printing the according solution.

This was my original code:

```
keywords = ["k1","k2","k3","k4","k5","k6","k7","k8","k9","kk"]

question_about_phone = input("What Seems to be the Problem? Please be percific but don't bombard us with too much info").lower()

file = open('code.txt','r')
solution = [line.strip(',') for line in file.readlines()]

for x in range(0, 10):

    if keywords[x] in question_about_phone:
        print(solution[x])
```

However in the middle of my Assessment I realised that u cant have it printing a solution for each keyword. So I decided to make it assign a value to a different list and then have many lines of

```
if list[1] and list[5] = "true:
 print(Solution[1]
```

and so on ...

however this is inefficient ;( is there anyway i can use a DICTIONARY with values and say something along the lines of:

`dictionary = [list[1] list[5],` (more combos)
then something like (probably a while loop)

```
for x in range(0,10):
    if dictionary[x] == "TRUE":
        print(solutions[x])
        end code
```

Comment: Please don't deface your questions after you have received good answers.

Comment: It is not permitted that you delete your own question. When posting it, you licensed it to stack exchange irrevocably under the CC BY SA license. It is no longer yours, and should you keep deleting it, the post will be locked.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
keywords = ["battery", "off", "broken"]
question_about_phone = input("What Seems to be the Problem?")

with open('code.txt', 'r') as file:
    solutions = {k:line.strip(',\n') for k, line in zip(keywords, file)}
    answers = [v for k, v in solutions.items() if k in question_about_phone]

if answers:
    print(answers)
else:
    print('Sorry, there are no answers to your question')
```

which, for example, with a file of

```
answer 4 battery
answer 4 off
answer 4 broken
...
```

and an input question of

```
What Seems to be the Problem? broken battery sunny
```

produces

```
['answer 4 broken', 'answer 4 battery']
```

basically `solutions` is built pairing the keywords and each line of the file.

Then `answers` is formed picking the values of those keywords that appear in the question

**However**, I strongly agree with Tim Seed's approach: it would be much more efficient to only look for the keywords present in the question instead of doing the opposite, since the possible answers outnumber the terms in the question.

In order to achieve that, simply change

```
answers = [solutions[k] for k in question_about_phone.split() if k in solutions]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly deduced that iterating through a list (array) is inefficient - and using a dictionary is an option.

So using your Example

```
keywords = {"k1": "Turn Power on","k2":"Turn Power Off"}
for k in ['Bad','k1','k2','bad']:
  if k in keywords:
    print("%s: Answer is %s"%(k,keywords[k]))
  else:
    print("%s: No idea what the issue is"%(k))
```

You should get Answers for k1,k2 - but not for the others....

Giving you output of

```
Bad: No idea what the issue is
k1: Answer is Turn Power on
k2: Answer is Turn Power Off 
bad: No idea what the issue is
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I assume that there is exactly one answer per keyword (from your example code).

You can then just return after the first answer has been found, as in:

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    if keywords[x] in question_about_phone:
        print(solution[x])
        return
print("No solution found, be more specific")
```

You can also iterate in a more general way:

```
for idx, kw in enumerate(keywords):
    if kw in question_about_phone:
        print(solutions[idx])
        return
```